# Excel Graph to PowerPoint C++/CLI Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Tags: excel, c++-cli, powerpoint, office-interop, msdn

I am trying to copy excel graphs and then pasting them into a PowerPoint using C++/CLI although I have run into difficulties when trying to use the Copy() method. Here is a simplified version of my code right now:

```
Worksheet = dynamic_cast<Excel::Worksheet^>(WS[3]);
chartObjects = dynamic_cast<Excel::ChartObjects^>(Worksheet->ChartObjects(paramMissing));
existingChartObject = dynamic_cast<Excel::ChartObject^>(chartObjects->Item(2));
existingChartObject->Copy();
shapeRange = Slide->Shapes->Paste();
```

but when I try this it give me an error of:

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Excel To PPT.exe`

`Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Now my Excel workbook has **6** graphs on each sheet starting on sheet 3. And if I copy all the graphs on sheet 3 and past them onto a slide like this.

**Call this attempt one**

```
for(count = 1, count <= 6; ++count){
    Worksheet = dynamic_cast<Excel::Worksheet^>(WS[2]);
    chartObjects = dynamic_cast<Excel::ChartObjects^>(Worksheet->ChartObjects(paramMissing));
    existingChartObject = dynamic_cast<Excel::ChartObject^>(chartObjects->Item(count));
    existingChartObject->Copy();
    shapeRange = Slide->Shapes->Paste();
}
```

Then there is no exception thrown. Now if I were try to do the same thing but start at graph 2 instead of 1 I get the exception thrown. Like this:

**Call this attempt two**

```
for(count = 2, count <= 6; ++count){
    Worksheet = dynamic_cast<Excel::Worksheet^>(WS[2]);
    chartObjects = dynamic_cast<Excel::ChartObjects^>(Worksheet->ChartObjects(paramMissing));
    existingChartObject = dynamic_cast<Excel::ChartObject^>(chartObjects->Item(count));
    existingChartObject->Copy();
    shapeRange = Slide->Shapes->Paste();
}
```

When I step through it and I hover over `existingCharObject` on the second attempt it is not empty and looks the exact same as in attempt 1.

Why would the second attempt throw an exception but the first wouldn't? I should be able to copy any excel ChartObject I want? It is forcing me to start at ChartObject 1 in the whole workbook and work my way up and not allowing me to randomly copy ChartObjects.

Let me know if there is more information you need. I did not want to past my whole project into this, this is the only part of the project that is giving me issues.